# When I leftclick on a favorite in nautilus the mouse grabs the icon

Tags: nautilus, mouse, touchpad, desktop-environments

Sometimes I have the problem, that when I tap on a folder from my favourites list in nautilus on the left with my touchpad, additionally to opening that folder the mouse also **grabs the folder** to move it up or down. I have to place it where it was to get the mouse free again.

If I log out and in again into my desktop the problem is gone. But it is really annoying (reloading the session with ALT+F2 "r" does not suffice).

It seems like this problem goes along wit a similar problem: on SmartGit I am not able to click on the shortcut-icons on the top any more, while the program still works (I have to use the menu commands instead)

(I use standard Ubuntu 21.04 on a lenovo 730-15iwl, upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: I already got this issue, I'm afraid this is a Gnome/Mutter bug (lag ?) and there is nothing to do about that.

Comment: Is there a bug report already? And a workaround would be fine